# oracle adf difference between two dates

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm trying to do a Project in college. 
i have problem in this code

```
Timestamp ts1=jbod1.timestampValue();             
Timestamp ts2=jbod2.timestampValue();
```

i need to calculate the duration between to columns. When I add any employee it will calculate duration automatically.
i need help fast guys please 
it shows this error

incompatible types java.sql.TimeStamp cannot be converted to oracle.jbo.domain.TimeStamp

```
public Number getDuration() {

            oracle.jbo.domain.Date jbod1=getVacstartdate();

            oracle.jbo.domain.Date jbod2 = getVacenddate();

            oracle.jbo.domain.Number DURATION;



                    Timestamp ts1=jbod1.timestampValue();
                    Timestamp ts2=jbod2.timestampValue();



                     long ndays=((ts2.getTime()-ts1.getTime())/86400000)+1 ;

                     DURATION=new oracle.jbo.domain.Number(ndays);

                      System.out.println("Number of Days    " +DURATION);

                    return DURATION;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend here. Especially if you are in a hurry!

Read the docs for [oracle.jbo.domain.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/api-reference-model/oracle/jbo/domain/Timestamp.html) and you'll see the constructors there. Use these to create instances of jbo timestamp. You can't convert one object type to another by assignment. This [post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2616105) may help.